# Instantiating a structure-enum

Tags: bixby

So I have a `structure-enum` that looks like:

```
integer (Id) {}

enum (Color) {
  symbol (red)
  symbol (orange)
  symbol (yellow)
  symbol (green)
  symbol (blue)
  symbol (indigo)
  symbol (violet)
}

structure-enum (ColorId) {
  property (color) {
    type (Color)
    min (Required)
    max (One)
  }
  property (id) {
    type (Id)
    min (Required)
    max (One)
  }
  constant: ColorId {
    color: (red)
    id: (1)
  }
  constant: ColorId {
    color: (orange)
    id: (2)
  }
  constant: ColorId {
    color: (yellow)
    id: (3)
  }
  constant: ColorId {
    color: (green)
    id: (4)
  }
  constant: ColorId {
    color: (blue)
    id: (5)
  }
  constant: ColorId {
    color: (indigo)
    id: (6)
  }
  constant: ColorId {
    color: (violet)
    id: (7)
  }
}
```

And I want to have an action that looks something like:

```
action (SomeAction) {
  collect {
    input (colorId) {
      type (ColorId)
      min (Required) 
      max (One)
    }
  }
  output (SomeOutput)
}
```

I want the user to be able to say one of the `Color`s (which I have vocab for) and have Bixby match that color to one of the `structure-enum`s and input that into my actions. So for example, the user could say "yellow" and Bixby would match that to the `structure-enum`:

```
constant: ColorId {
  color: (yellow)
  id: (3)
}
```

And use that as an input to my action. Basically I want to know how to take a user utterance and instantiate that into a `structure-enum`. How do I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

structure-enum does fit this usage case.

You may have the following constant and the syntax is still valid.

```
constant: ColorId {
    color: (red)
    id: (1)
  }
  constant: ColorId {
    color: (red)
    id: (11)
  }
  constant: ColorId {
    color: (red)
    id: (31)
  }
```

Keep the enum `Color` and do a look up in JS file and return `Id`.

Comment: I was hoping to do this without using a JS file which I think kind of defeats the point of having a `structure-enum` as then I have to have all the possible values defined in two places (and then if I ever update it I need to make sure I update both). I was hoping that if my action had an input of `structure-enum` and the user said a `Color` that Bixby would be smart enough to index into the `structure-enum` and instantiate it with the correct Id. Oh well.

Comment: There is no need to define `structure-enum` in your case, just use a normal structure and keep Color as enum. Only need to define/update the table in JS file.